# Redshift Optimization

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am looking for some help with optimizing the below. Is there a method if Redshift that can be used to eliminate the need to call the sub select each time since they are virtually the same for different fields:

```
select 
       IdText AS EquipmentPointCode, 
       OnRLT AS Downtime,
       (   SELECT OnRLT FROM temp_pointsvr_uptime_dataset WHERE IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1) AND OnRLT > t1.OnRLT ORDER BY OnRLT ASC LIMIT 1) AS Uptime,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value1 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1) AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value1,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value2 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1) AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value2,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value3 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1) AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value3,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value4 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1) AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value4,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value5 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1) AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value5,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value6 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1) AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value6,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value7 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1) AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value7,
       (   SELECT StateDefault_Value1 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1) AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS StateDefault_Value1,
       (   SELECT StateDefault_Value2 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1) AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS StateDefault_Value2,
       (   SELECT StateDefault_Value3 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1) AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS StateDefault_Value3,
       'FM 10' AS Equipment
FROM temp_pointsvr_downtime t1
WHERE  IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1)
```

Comment: OMG! What are you trying to achieve with this statement? I suspect you can simply use a join, but it is hard to understand your query. Can you please re-write your question with a simplified use-case (eg not as many sub-selects), and a description of what you are trying to achieve? If possible, show what is in your tables and what output you are trying to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like what you're trying to do can be accomplished using case statements, but without seeing an example of the tables/data you're working with it's tough to determine.

Tackling just the nested select statements, you should be able to use a common table expression to hit the table one time, instead of re-selecting from it each time:

```
WITH
 id_text_filter AS (
    SELECT IDtext
    FROM list_of_ids
    WHERE rownum = 1
) 

SELECT 
       IdText AS EquipmentPointCode, 
       OnRLT AS Downtime,
       (   SELECT OnRLT FROM temp_pointsvr_uptime_dataset WHERE IdText = (select IDtext from list_of_ids where rownum =1) AND OnRLT > t1.OnRLT ORDER BY OnRLT ASC LIMIT 1) AS Uptime,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value1 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE ti.IdText = f.IDtext AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value1,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value2 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE ti.IdText = f.IDtext AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value2,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value3 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE ti.IdText = f.IDtext AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value3,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value4 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE ti.IdText = f.IDtext AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value4,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value5 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE ti.IdText = f.IDtext AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value5,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value6 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE ti.IdText = f.IDtext AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value6,
       (   SELECT LineDefault_Value7 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE ti.IdText = f.IDtext AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS LineDefault_Value7,
       (   SELECT StateDefault_Value1 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE ti.IdText = f.IDtext AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS StateDefault_Value1,
       (   SELECT StateDefault_Value2 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE ti.IdText = f.IDtext AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS StateDefault_Value2,
       (   SELECT StateDefault_Value3 FROM temp_not_pointsvr_downtime WHERE ti.IdText = f.IDtext AND OffRLT = t1.OnRLT  ORDER BY ResetRLT DESC Limit 1) AS StateDefault_Value3,
       'FM 10' AS Equipment
FROM temp_pointsvr_downtime t1
JOIN id_text_filter f ON ti.IDtext = f.IDtext
WHERE  IdText = (SELECT IDtext FROM list_of_ids WHERE rownum =1)
```

Again, I'm not sure if this code will work straight out of the box, as I'm not able to test it. But the idea should be similar:

1) Create a common table expression with the data you want to use as a filter
2) Join to that table in the main SELECT
3) Define WHERE clauses based on an equality to the common table expression.